# Changing to directories with spaces in the name

Tags: linux, bash

Feel silly asking this question, but can't seem to change directory to `Windows XP IE7`.  See below for what I have tried.

```
[root@localhost VirtualBox VMs]# ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 4 justMe justMe 4096 Dec 19 07:20 Windows XP IE6
drwxr-xr-x 4 justMe justMe 4096 Dec 19 06:48 Windows XP IE7
[root@localhost VirtualBox VMs]# cd Windows XP IE6
-bash: cd: Windows: No such file or directory
[root@localhost VirtualBox VMs]# cd Win*
[root@localhost Windows XP IE6]# ls -l
total 3558896
drwx------ 2 justMe justMe       4096 Dec 19 07:20 Logs
drwx------ 2 justMe justMe       4096 Dec 19 07:20 Snapshots
-rw------- 1 justMe justMe      18529 Dec 19 07:20 Windows XP IE6.vbox
-rw------- 1 justMe justMe      18586 Dec 19 07:20 Windows XP IE6.vbox-prev
-rw------- 1 justMe justMe 3640700928 Jul 24 12:03 Windows XP IE6.vdi
[root@localhost Windows XP IE6]#
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Bash, you must [quote](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting) command arguments that have whitespace in them.

This is one reason why avoiding such whitespace is a  good idea.

You need:

```
$ cd "Windows XP IE6"
```

Comment: Yes, I feel silly!  Thanks

Comment: The alternative is to use backslashes to escape spaces:
`cd Windows\ XP\ IE6`

Comment: The <tab> button is your friend is bash, it will autocomplete.